# IOS emdash deletes previous character

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, validation

I have a text file where it only allows letters and numbers. however when ios users insert an emdash by double tapping a dash " - " it will delete whatever character before it. this only happens on ios devices

I am using regex to filter the input instantly. here is my code:

```
let text = event.target.value;
let regref = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
text  = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\—]/g,"");
let str = event.target.value;


let text = event.target.value;
let regref = new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
text  = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\—]/g,"");
let str = event.target.value;


if (str.length > 6) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  return;
}
setTimeout(function(){
  if (!regref.test(text)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  text = text.replace('_', "");

  text = text.replace('-',"");
}, 200);
setReferralCode((referralCode = caps));
```

notice in text  = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-\—]/g,""); i have allowed the - and — in hope that i can display an error message instead of preventing its input, however even with that if o input: "aaabbb" followed by double dash the string change to "aaabb—"

```
   **FIXED UPDATE**
```

a colleague helped me out with this by using _.debounce();
and having a temp variable that stores the previous valid code.
it looked like this :

```
 let text = event.target.value as string;
console.log(text);
var emRegExp = new RegExp(/[–—\s\.]/g);
if (text[text.length - 1] == "-" || emRegExp.test(text[text.length - 1])) {
  text = lastReferralCode
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .toUpperCase()
    .trim()
    .substr(0, 6);
} else {
  text = text
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .toUpperCase()
    .trim()
    .substr(0, 6);
  setIsDashBefore(false);
}
```

I thought of sharing this in case anyone had the same issue in the future. This could be troublesome for some web based hyper apps. Android devices would delete the previous character if the input is double "space" with some android keyboards. While iPhone do the same with its double " -" character.
just as @A Haworth mentioned, the ios or android is dealing with the characters as double which what causing the issue.

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet as it’s easier to test things. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what the reason for the setTimeout is and in particular why 200milisecs?

Comment: The timeout was meant to delay user ffrom input so the regex can test properly, however i figured it that ios will still change the character into emspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a colleague helped me out with this by using _.debounce();
and having a temp variable that stores the previous valid code.
it looked like this :

```
 let text = event.target.value as string;
console.log(text);
var emRegExp = new RegExp(/[–—\s\.]/g);
if (text[text.length - 1] == "-" || emRegExp.test(text[text.length - 1])) {
  text = lastReferralCode
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .toUpperCase()
    .trim()
    .substr(0, 6);
} else {
  text = text
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "")
    .replace(/\s/g, "")
    .toUpperCase()
    .trim()
    .substr(0, 6);
  setIsDashBefore(false);
}
```

I thought of sharing this in case anyone had the same issue in the future. This could be troublesome for some web based hyper apps. Android devices would delete the previous character if the input is double "space" with some android keyboards. While iPhone do the same with its double " -" character.
just as @A Haworth mentioned, the ios or android is dealing with the characters as double which what causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if there is a possibility your code runs into timing problems - the system is dealing with a dash at the same time as the code is trying to deal with it.

IOS's activity on receiving a '-' character is to look to see if the previous character in the input is also a '-'. If it is it converts the two to the single character emspace. By that time though any event listening code has seen two hyphens.

If we 'interfere' and remove the first hyphen from the string IOS is 'confused' and removes what it thinks is two '-' characters, which means it removes the next character back in the input value string.

To get round this we can look for the hyphen character and not remove it from the input value immediately.

Here is a snippet, taking the event being looked at the keyup event:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
let timing = false; //set to true if we have a timeout set
let lastChWasHyphen = false; //set to true on every odd numbered hyphen

function keyup(event) {
  
  if ( event.key == '-' ) { 
    if (!lastChWasHyphen) { alert('You cannot have a - character'); }
    lastChWasHyphen = !lastChWasHyphen;
  }
  else { lastChWasHyphen = false; }
 
  if (!lastChWasHyphen) { input.value  = input.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,""); }
}

input.addEventListener('keyup',keyup);
```

```html
<input />
```

Drawback: the hyphen character does not get removed until another character is typed. It's not safe to, for example, set a timeout on this as the user can type a hyphen twice with a gap to get an emspace on IOS. The only thing to do here would be to put up a warning message on the odd numbered - characters as suggested in the question.

Caveat: the question was specifically about IOS's allowing input of emspace. I do not know whether IOS, or indeed any other systems, have other special double-character mapping to single character methods.

Comment: This is actually a good way but i cant have any alerts in this. it have to be responsive almost instantly.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand about the alert. I just put it there to tell the user if they had entered a dash. You can use any method you like to tell them (e.g. a popover box).

Comment: Aa i thought its important to stop the user from input or make the input tag as blur. that would fix the problem, however i was required to only display an error message under the input field.